# Python script doesn't write Greek characters to text file when started from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, text-files

I have a batch file that runs a Python script. The Python script writes text to a text file.

Now, normally this works fine, even with accented letters like à or ö, but not when Greek or Hebrew characters should be written. Then it doesn't write anything.

If I run the Python script from IDLE, any kind of text is written to the file and no errors appear in the Shell window.

Here's my test code:
Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
akasi='test' + unicode('aergשריש','utf-8')
print akasi
text_file = codecs.open('Temp.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
text_file.write(akasi)
text_file.close()
```

Batch file

```
@Echo Off
cd /D C:
start /min /wait python "C:\Python27\Scripts\Temp03_27_310.py"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Angela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing too much work -- there's no need to encode your data because it's already in UTF-8 as specified in your first commented line.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
akasi='test aergשריש'
print akasi
with open('temp.txt', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(akasi)
```

Comment: Well, the data of the actual script isn't. :) However, I could work it out following your direction and now it seems to work (fingers crossed). Thanks so much.

Comment: Note: this solution is for Python 2.7. For Python 3 you would have to specify the encoding explicitly when opening the file:  `with open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:`